# jQuery - target.href with <a href="#"><img></a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have an a ajax method that hijacks every link in the HTML and `preventDefault` and then loads the `loadPage` function().

The method works on all other links that does not have a `<img>` inside. But when a `<a>` has a `<img>` inside the method `clickEvent.target.href` does not seem to work.

The `var url` in this instance returns undefined in the console, but on any other links it returns the `href`.

I'm guessing there is something wrong with I use the target method in this instance?

```
$('#container a').click(function(clickEvent){
         var url = clickEvent.target.href;
         if(url.match(urlWebServer)) {
                     clickEvent.preventDefault();
                     loadPage(url);
         }
});



<div id="user_img">        
    <a href="somepage.html"><img src="img_user/self.jpg" class="self" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you shouldn't use the `clickEvent.target` because is the target that was clicked. In your case the target **isn't the `a` but is the `img` it contains**.

Events in fact bubble up, so you click the image and the `click` event propagates to the top (up to the `a`) and triggers the event delegate you provided.

The solution is to change that line to

```
var url = this.href;
```

Or if you prefer to get the value through jQuery use

```
var url = $(this).attr('href');
```

The first one is faster.

The solution is that `this` in the handler refers to the DOM element you attach the handler to. So `this` will refer to the `a`.

Answer (score 4):

If you use jQuery to select and bind, why not use jQuery for the rest of your action?

```
$('#container a').click(function(event){
     var url = $(this).attr('href');
     if(url.match(urlWebServer)) {
                 event.preventDefault();
                 loadPage(url);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because `clickEvent.target` refers to the element which received the click, not the element to which the event listener was attached. Use `this` instead, which corresponds to the correct element.

`var url = this.href;`

Also note that you don't need to do `$(this).prop` or `$(this).attr`; you can safely access the `.href` property of an anchor element without needing to create another jQuery instance and call another method.

Answer (score 1):

The `target` is the actual element that event was triggered on, which can be any of the children of the element you attached it to.

Use `this` to reference the link instead.

```
var url = $(this).prop("href");
```

Comment: As far as I know, it's .attr(), not .prop(), since it's an HTML attribute and not a DOM property.

Comment: @daan I am pretty sure it is https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLAnchorElement